# How to delete more than 1 pointers point to same address

Tags: c++, pointers, delete-operator

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [how to safely delete multiple pointers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3932367/how-to-safely-delete-multiple-pointers)

As the code below:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main(int argc, _TCHAR* argv[])
{
    int *p, *q;
    q = new int;
    p = q;
    delete q;
    q = NULL;
    cout << p << "  " <<q << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

`p` point to `q`. When I delete `q` and `q` = `NULL`, `p` still points to the old address. 
Does anyone have any method to make `p` point to `q` `NULL` automatically?
Because if in a program there are lots of pointers that point to the same address and we can't make them point to `NULL` it would bring problems.

Comment: well, a pointer to a pointer to a variable is just two pointers to a variable, so you have to do it manually. Or try doing it as an array, where you have p[2], and then have two indivual poiinters, then delete them by iterating through the array.

Comment: So unlike std::shared_ptr, where the last reference finally frees the goods, you want the object (and int in this case) to know all references to it and clear them *all* when *any* of them are free'd ?

Comment: Can't make `p` a reference? http://ideone.com/ahFmH

Answer (score 4):

There is a type of smart pointer which can do the job. There may be issues with thread safety with this code,(in fact I guarantee there will be).

```
template <class T>
class DoublyLinkedSmartPointer
{
   public:
      DoublyLinkedSmartPointer(const DoublyLinkedSmartPointer &other);
      DoublyLinkedSmartPointer& operator=(const DoublyLinkedSmartPointer& other);
      virtual ~DoubleLinkedSmartPointer();
      T * operator*();
      const T* operator*() const;

      void freeAll();
   private:

      DoublyLinkedSmartPointer *next, *previous;
      T * data;
}
```

The basic idea is, whenever a copy is made of the smart pointer, you add the copy into the
list using the smart pointer used to initialise it. And when you remove the pointer, you
free it from the list.

Now, the tricky bit, since every pointer knows every other pointer, you can step through the list from any point, and set data to NULL in every node.

Okay, so that's how you could do it. But more importantly, don't do it. You are almost certainly going to create code which is hard to maintain, and near impossible to debug. The best memory management strategies are the simplest.

Answer (score 1):

The general advise for C++ programs is to avoid elementary pointers, precisely to avoid the issues you're having. Instead, use the language's (or more precisely its standard library's) methods to deal with pointers:

1 use containers, such as `std::vector`, instead of pointers to (chunks of) memory allocated on the heap

2 use `std::unique_ptr` and `std::shared_ptr` (and `std::weak_ptr`) to manage objects allocated on the heap. This only works properly in C++11 with its move semantics, see the standard header .

advantages: automatic de-allocation without leaving dangling pointers; exception safety (throwing an exception and stack-rewinding does not leak memory).